# From h2o, is there a way to export N folder cross validation results into a dataframe?

Tags: python, h2o, sparkling-water

I am using H2O sparking water to built GBM model. I know we can view the N folder cross validation results using code below:

```
gbm_model.model_performance(xval = True)
```

But is there a way to save each folder's model performance into a data frame? For example, save each folder's AUC into a data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating your model, you can set `keep_cross_validation_models=True` and then obtain the models by calling `cross_validation_models()` on your model object. Then you can obtain each model's performance as usual. See [the documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/keep_cross_validation_models.html#keep-cross-validation-models).